# Contacts shows truecaller and paytm links

Tags: contacts

I use LETV with marshmallow. I use PAytm and truecaller. recently these apps started to show up their pay for the friend and send money links and it's irritating. I don't want to uninstall these apps but I want contacts to show only call option.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you've to proceed.

**Step 1:** *Go to Settings.*

**Step 2:** *Scroll down to Accounts*

[image]

**Step 3:** *Choose either Paytm or Truecaller.*

[image]

**Step 4:** *Disable contact sync for both.*

[image]

[image]